# Create form dynamically in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

A simple question:

I have one form, it returns one number and I need create this number of labels **in Controller.**

I try:

```
$form2 = $this->createFormBuilder();

for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $name = 'column'.$i;
    $form2->add($name,'number');
}

$form2->getForm();
```

I think it should very simple, but i can't..

Comment: you're trying to add an embedding form several time? If yes have a look on this it'll help you : http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: I didn't to use one Type and Class

Comment: So your form don't use entity? Then just add a for loop in twig to duplicate your field

Comment: Yes. And how would I take the values ​​of the labels in Controller?

Comment: can you show us your form type, controller method and twig corresponding to this form?

Comment: I don't have form type.. If it was just a label I would have done: `$form = $this->createFormBuilder()->add('column','number')->getForm();` in Controller and `{{ form_widget(form) }}` in twig..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18581/discussion-between-coussinsky-and-fabiano-palaoro)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with an array / hash map instead of a real object.

Here is an example :

```
// Create the array
$dataObj = array();

$dataObj['data1'] = '';
$dataObj['data2'] = 'default';
// ... do a loop here
$dataObj['data6'] = 'Hello';

// Create the form
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($dataObj);
foreach($dataObj as $key => $val)
{
    $fieldType = 'text'; // Here, everything is a text, but you can change it based on $key, or something else
    $formBuilder->add($key, $fieldType);
}
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();

// Process the form
$request = $this->get('request');
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
{
    $form->bind($request); // For symfony 2.1.x
    // $form->bind($this->get('request')->request->get('form')); // For symfony 2.0.x
    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $dataObj = $form->getData();
        foreach($dataObj as $key => $val)
        {
            echo $key . ' = ' . $val . '<br />';
        }
        exit('Done');
    }
}

// Render
    return $this->render('Aaa:Bbb:ccc.html.twig', array(
    'requestForm' => $form->createView()));
```