# Form in Symfony 2 whose fields change in number and purpose according to external data

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am building an application using Symfony 2, and one of the pages contains a large form, which has a number of fixed fields but also a number of fields whose presence and number depends entirely on related data taken from the DB.  More specifically, the form poses a number of questions, and the questions themselves come from the DB, having different text and IDs.  The answers need to be stored in the DB, linked to the questions.

I've read up on how Symfony handles forms ([Basic Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)), including the relationship between a Form object and the data object backing it, creating Fields from the Form object, and validating input according to rules applied to the Form object.

Since I don't want a fixed Form object I looked at how you're meant to dynamically modify Forms ([Dynamic Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)), but the examples there seem to be about choosing whether to show certain pre-defined fields, or controlling the options in the fields, not completely generating new fields from scratch, which is what I want.

I had a look at the [Symfony page on Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html), and it seemed relevant, but I couldn't quite get my head around how it would help me.  They seem more about mapping a Form object to an Entity than mapping complex form submissions to a Form object.

I did see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14606635/84649) where the object backing the Form object is just an array, which also seemed relevant: I thought that maybe the answer was to generate some anonymous object with the dynamic fields in, and then make a form from that, but I don't see how I'd set up Symfony validation on it, and my form is not completely different each time, so doesn't need to be entirely anonymous.

What is the best way to achieve this using Symfony 2, ideally without giving up such framework benefits as easy validation etc?

EDIT I hadn't heard of [Symfony Form Collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) before, and it looks like this might do what I want - each Question in my case would map to an individual subform object.  I'll update again if I try it out successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in the end what I wanted wasn't a truly dynamic form (but thanks to @Cerad for that code), but one using Collections where the number of certain child form items was variable.

So I essentially followed the [Symfony Docs about Collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty broad but this might help focus.

I have what I call a DynamicFormType which can add elements to a form based on a configuration items array.

```
class DynamicFormType extends AbstractType
{
protected $name;
protected $items;

public function getName() { return $this->name; }

public function __construct($name, $items)
{
    $this->name  = $name;
    $this->items = $items;
}
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{   
    foreach($this->items as $name => $item)
    {
        switch($item['type'])
        {
            case 'radio':

                $attr = array('class' => 'radio-medium');
                $builder->add($name,'choice',array(
                    'label'       => $item['label'],
                    'required'    => false,
                    'attr'        => $attr,
                    'empty_value' => false,
                    'expanded'    => true,
                    'multiple'    => false,
                    'choices'     => $item['choices'],
                ));
                break;

            case 'select':

                $attr = array();
                $builder->add($name,'choice',array(
                    'label'       => $item['label'],
                    'required'    => false,
                    'attr'        => $attr,
                    'empty_value' => false,
                    'expanded'    => false,
                    'multiple'    => false,
                    'choices'     => $item['choices'],
                ));
                break;

            case 'text':

                $attr = array();

                if (isset($item['size'])) $attr['size'] = $item['size'];

                $builder->add($name,'text',array(
                    'label'    => $item['label'],
                    'required' => false,
                    'attr'     => $attr,
                ));
                break;

            case 'textarea':

                $attr = array();

                if (isset($item['rows'])) $attr['rows'] = $item['rows'];
                if (isset($item['cols'])) $attr['cols'] = $item['cols'];

                $builder->add($name,'textarea',array(
                    'label'    => $item['label'],
                    'required' => false,
                    'attr'     => $attr,
                ));
                break;

            case 'collection':

                $dynamicType = new DynamicFormType($name,$item['items']);
                $builder->add($name,$dynamicType,array(
                    'label'    => false,
                    'required' => false,
                ));
                break;
        }
    }
    return; if ($options);
}
}
```

I trust you can see how the items array is used to create form elements.  In my application I use this with:

```
    $basicType = new DynamicFormType('basic',$project->getPlan());
    $builder->add('basic',$basicType, array('label' => false));
```

$project->getPlan() returns the items array which describes the various elements I want to add.

Hopefully, you can start with something like this and figure out what elements need to be added from your data structure.  I didn't need validation here but it should be easy enough to add constraint information to you elements once you get things working.

Comment: Thanks for that, very helpful.  I do see how you could use that approach to add arbitrary fields to the form.  However, you've got no data class backing the Form object, so where does the data go on submission, were you handling that all yourself rather than with the framework?

Comment: And I wonder if you have an idea how you'd add constraints to it?  Would there even be a call to isValid, would it do anything with no data_class, and hence nothing to validate ?

Comment: Found basic manual constraint addition here: http://knplabs.com/blog/2011/09/27/symfony-validators-standalone/

Comment: What's the `return; if ($options);` at the end?

Comment: My Netbeans IDE always flags unused variables.  Most of the time I like it.  But in some cases it's a pain.  The never executed if statement suppresses the IDE warning.